# Over which scalar structures, minimal or not minimal, can vector spaces be defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I am working with this list of axioms for a vector space, listed on the Wikipedia page (here, I will write vectors with big letters and scalars with small ones):

1) $U+(V+W)=(U+V)+W$

2) $U+V=V+U$

3) $V+0=V$

4) $V+(-V)=0$

5) $a(bV)=(ab)V$

6) $1V=V$

7) $a(U+V)=aU+aV$

8) $(a+b)V=aV+bV$

As we see, the first three axioms have nothing to do with scalars, because zero in the third axiom is zero vector, but then, in the fourth axiom we have $-V$ and there is a need for a interpretation of the $-$ symbol and it seems that $-V$ can be defined as $(-1)V$, but I do not know is that a right approach, and $-1$ would here be an element of the scalars such that $-1+1=1+(-1)=0$, where here $0$ is scalar zero.

The fifth axiom does not require (or if it is, it maybe does not need to) that $ab$ is an element of the scalar structure if $a$ and $b$ are.

The sixth axiom requires that in the scalar structure $1$ exists and it probably must have the property that $1a=a1=a$.

Finally, the eight axiom also maybe does not need to have $a+b$ as an element of scalar structure if $a$ and $b$ are.

But even if we require that $ab$ is an element of the scalar structure whenever $a$ and $b$ are and that $a+b$ is an element of the scalar structure whenever $a$ and $b$ are, it seems to me that scalar structures over which vector spaces are defined does not need to be fields, and if they need to then it should somehow follow from the axioms and I do not see does that follow from the axioms?

You understand what exactly I am interested in, so, can you tell me more about issues like this one, and, if scalar structures over which vector spaces can be defined does not need to be fields, what can they be?

Comment: I don't understand why you say that $ab$ or $a+b$ are not required to be scalars. If they aren't then what is $(ab)V$ or $(a+b)V$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. If we require them to be elements of the same structure (although it seems to me that they need not to be), it still seems that scalar structures need not to be fields, right?

Comment: Axioms 1, 2, 3, 4 there (along with the fact that $0$ exists) are exactly the axioms of an abelian group. Axioms 5, 6, 7, 8 are exactly the axioms for a unital ring to act on the abelian group, called a [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)#Formal_definition). If you want to get back to a vector space, all you need to do is to require that ring to be a field, so all your scalars satisfy $ab = ba$, and a nonzero scalar always has an inverse: for each $a$ there exists an $a^{-1}$ such that $a a^{-1} = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to state the axioms, all you need is that your scalars have :

- an addition $(a,b)\mapsto a+b$
- a multiplication $(a,b)\mapsto a\cdot b$
- a constant $1$

Since these operations must interact nicely with those on the vectors, it seems reasonable to ask that $a\cdot 1=a=1\cdot a$ for all $a$, that the addition of scalars is commutative and associative, and that the multiplication is distributive over the addition. Given the third and fourth axiom, it would make sense to require also the existence of another constant $0$ for which $0+a=a=a+0$ for all $a$, and the existence of additive inverse for every element $a$ (i.e. an element $-a$ such that $a+(-a)=0=(-a)+a$), then your scalars form what is called a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)). Then you can define vector spaces over a ring by requiring exactly the axioms you have written, but to emphasize the fact that the scalars do not form a field, they are actually called **modules over a ring**. They have some similarities with vector spaces, but some things do not work in the same way : for example modules do not necessarily have bases or a well-defined dimension.

Note that if you don't require the fourth axiom, you would probably not require the scalars to have additive inverses ; in that case your scalars would form a [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring), and your axioms (minus the fourth one) would form a module over a semiring. There are other variants; for example some authors do not require the existence of $1$ in a ring or semiring, and then they do not require the sixth axiom.